# How to duplicate rows in SQL by partition?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having a bit of trouble creating a query to duplicate some rows
I have a table that looks like this:

| country | code |
| --- | --- |
| EU | A |
| AR | B |
| AR | D |
| MX | A |

I need to duplicate each row by defining a "partition" column, let's say country, it'd take each distinct value of that column and then repeat the other rows, the column indicator is a bool that allows knowing which was the original country, so the final result should look like this

| partition | code | indicator |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EU | A | True |
| EU | B | False |
| EU | D | False |
| EU | A | False |
| AR | A | False |
| AR | B | True |
| AR | D | True |
| AR | A | False |
| MX | A | False |
| MX | B | False |
| MX | D | False |
| MX | A | True |

How can I achieve this using SQL? (I'm mostly using postgresql)

Comment: Is it intended that there are two `A` rows for each country?

Comment: Yes, it could be any really, there is no rule for which value should be in that column, it could be a free text

Comment: The actual value doesn't matter. But there is an `A` for `MX` and an `A` for `EU` in the original data and this results in two (`MX`, `A`) and two (`EU`, `A`) rows in the result. Is this intended? If so, could there be more than one (`MX`, `A`) rows in the original data?

Comment: That is right, it could there be more than one (MX, A) I solved it by adding an id and using a cross-join over the id, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This query

```
select countries.country, codes.code, 
   case
      when (m.country is null) THEN 'False'
      else 'True'
   end indicator
from (
  select distinct code
  from master) codes
join ( 
  select distinct country
  from master) countries
on 1=1
left join master m
on m.code = codes.code
  and m.country = countries.country
order by countries.country, codes.code;
```

gives this result, which is what you requested, modulo the duplicate (`country`, `code`) tuples.

| country | code | indicator |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AR | A | False |
| AR | B | True |
| AR | D | True |
| EU | A | True |
| EU | B | False |
| EU | D | False |
| MX | A | True |
| MX | B | False |
| MX | D | False |

I used this setup

```
create table master(
  country varchar(20),
  code varchar(20)
);


insert into master (country, code) values
    ('EU',  'A'),
    ('AR',  'B'),
    ('AR',  'D'),
    ('MX',  'A');
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oW5ubUCRWMP7GvUa9QK3Sy/0)

It works by first determining all the row that are required, which is the cartesian product of the distinct codes and countries. If you don't take the distinct codes you can eventually achieve at the requirements as currently written, but I currently can't believe that is really what you want.

You then do an outer join to the original table and use a simple case expression for the `indicator`.

Comment: I think it might be a feasible solution, but I might have troubles since I have a lot more columns that those in the example but I get some ideas
Thanks